# how to mask raster by exact outline of shapefile in R?

Tags: r, polygon, crop, mask, r-raster

I am trying to mask a raster by a shapefile. So, I have used the following code:

```
mat=matrix(colMeans(x),nrow=length(lon(x)),ncol=length(lat(x))) 
# x is gridded rainfall data
mat_new <- apply(t(mat),2,rev) 
library(raster) 
r=raster(mat_new,xmn=min(lon(x)),xmx=max(lon(x)),ymn=min(lat(x)),ymx=max(lat(x))) 
r2 <- mask(r,shp_proj) 
plot(r2) 
plot(shp_proj,add=T)
```

And following output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9R9H.png)

Since there are blank cells at the boundary, I have modified the code as:

```
mat=matrix(colMeans(x),nrow=length(lon(x)),ncol=length(lat(x))) 
# x is gridded rainfall data
mat_new <- apply(t(mat),2,rev) 
library(raster) 
r=raster(mat_new,xmn=min(lon(x)),xmx=max(lon(x)),ymn=min(lat(x)),ymx=max(lat(x))) 
shp_ras <- rasterize(shp_proj, r, getCover=TRUE) 
shp_ras[shp_ras==0] <- NA 
plot(mask(r, shp_ras)) 
plot(shp_proj, add=T)
```

and get the following output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meUtl.png)

However, this is also not the desired output. I want to crop the raster by exact outline of shapefile. I want a output like following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Hir.png)

Is there any way to accomplish this in R? Please help.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/177625/get-distances-between-boundaries-from-an-spatialpolygon-and-raster-pixels) can help.

Comment: Can you post a fully reproducible example that includes `x`?

Comment: You can't really clip a coarse raster that close to an irregularly shaped vector. You might be able to vectorize the raster and clip that way if that suits your needs.

Comment: This was the best I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66206252/crop-geographical-boundaries-in-a-heatmap-in-r-ggplot